# JS Code not executing after refresh action

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

My app currently has a dynamic action that triggers on the change of a select list item and contains three events:

1. Refresh of an Interactive Grid

This is important because the interactive grid source query contains the value of the select list in its where clause.

2. Execute PL/SQL code, pulls some table data
3. Execute JS Code, takes some values from action 2 and then selects certain rows in the interactive grid that was refreshed in step 1 by using `view.setSelectedRecords()`

This works perfectly fine without the refresh as the same thing happens in other places within the same oracle page, but when I add the refresh action the rows don't get selected and as far as I can tell from some `console.log()` debugging, everything gets ran, but the rows don't get selected.

I have tried using the "after refresh" dynamic action for the second two events but this does not work either, I think it is because after refresh isn't supported for IG but I'm not positive.

I also have the "Fire on Initialization option unchecked for all three of my actions"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out quickly, I divided my one dynamic action into two different ones.

1. The first dynamic action is triggered on the change of the select list mentioned in the beginning of the problem, this dynamic action refreshes the interactive grid.
2. The second action is triggered on "page change [interactive grid]."  As it turns out refreshing the interactive grid region triggers this event.  In the "When" settings of this dynamic action I made the selection type "Region" and the region, my interactive grid.  This dynamic action executes all the JS and PL/SQL I need which didn't end up being the cause of the problem.

Comment: Add some more details, and probably some code samples, to make clear what you did.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).